# Adding values to complex dictionary Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am new to Swift and am having difficulty adding a new value to a complex dictionary. The below code updates values that already exist in the dictionary (e.g., Jerry and Beth), but if I try to add a new value, the dictionary shows only two values rather than three.

```
var locals: [String: Dictionary<String, String>] = ["Jerry":["City":Destination.Seattle.rawValue,"Preference": TravellingPreference.Adventurer.rawValue, "Gender": Gender.Male.rawValue],"Beth":["City":Destination.Seattle.rawValue,"Preference":TravellingPreference.Foodie.rawValue, "Gender": Gender.Female.rawValue]]

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    let citySelected = localInput[0][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    let preferenceSelected = localInput[1][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1)]
    var localInformation = LocalsInformation().locals
   if let name = nameTextField.text{
        localInformation[name]?["City"] = citySelected
        localInformation[name]?["Preference"] = preferenceSelected
        localInformation[name]?["Gender"] = "Female"
    print(localInformation)
    }

}
```

Comment: 1st, did you set a breakpoint and make sure your `if let` is getting called.
2nd, have you tried calling `localInformation.addValue(forKey:)` instead of assigning a value for a key.
3rd, if the username entered is Jerry or Beth it could override the existing values for those keys.

Comment: 1. Yes, I sent a breakpoint on print(localInformation), and if let is getting called and my code is properly storing values (ex. "Jane" for name, "Boston" for citySelected, and "Adventurer" for preferenceSelected. 2. I tried calling addValue on localInformation, but it doesn't seem to accept that function. 3. I plan to set-up a username system to differentiate the individuals in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
localInformation[name]?["City"] = citySelected
```

The `?` basically means (in this context) that nothing is done if `localInformation[name]` is `nil`, which is most likely the case. You probably want to do this:

```
localInformation[name] = [
    "City": citySelected,
    "Preference": preferenceSelected,
    "Gender": "Female"
]
```

Having said that, I would greatly advise you to use `struct`s rather than dictionaries wherever you can. It will be easier to deal with (because you can't misspell a key and you won't have to deal with as many optionals), and it will make your code clearer overall.

Comment: @LEisdorfer I'm glad I could help. Consider marking my answer as correct if you have no further questions. :)

Comment: I have another quick question. When I add a new individual to my dictionary, the data is not persisting (i.e., I set a breakpoint and can see a new person in my dictionary, but when I run my app again, the person is no longer in the dictionary). Is this because I am making a copy of the dictionary when I set it equal to localInformation? I tried to directly change the value of LocalsInformation().locals, so that the value would persist, but I am having trouble doing so. Any suggestions on the syntax?

Comment: @LEisdorfer That's because the dictionary is created each time the app runs. You would need to use `NSUserDefaults` or `Core Data` for that, you'll find lots of tutorials online if you google those terms.